# is there a delete grammar in lex and yacc?

Tags: yacc, context-free-grammar

In common grammar in lex and yacc,

```
A : aB
B : bc
```

The above grammar can deduce 'abc' into symbol 'A'

Further,I want to convert 'A' to 'S' by a delete operation

for example,

```
S : A`delete(c)`
```

combine all grammar above,and we can deduce 'ab' into 'S'

is there a similar grammar in lex and yacc?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

(F)lex patterns are essentially regular expressions of thr mathematical variety, with some convenience operators (such as character classes). (F)lex doesn't implement thr plethora of non-regular "Regex" operators found in most regex libraries. In theory, it is possible to implement a set difference operator without straying out of the firmal language definition of regular expression, since regular languages are closed over conjunction and inversion. In practice, implementation of this operator is uncommon. (The Ragel stare machine generator has it, but I don't know of any regex library which does.)

Yacc/bison only implement context-free grammars described in BNF. Context-free languages are *not*  closed over inversion or conjunction, so it is hard to see how any CFG-basef parser generator might tackle suxh a feature.

Comment: Understood. Here is the original problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017344/transform-text-with-given-pattern hope it will illustrate what I really want to do.